# How to gracefully switch back to master without being ahead on commits after a code review

Tags: git

I pulled from a refs/for/master branch, which we use for code reviews.

I'm now ahead of master by 2 commits.

How do I get rid of these two commits, to get back to normal?

I've tried

```
git reset --hard
git pull origin master
git checkout master
```

But I'm still ahead of master by two commits. I've looked for this online, but there's nothing here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout master # just to be sure
git reset --hard origin/master
```

is the command you want. It resets your local master HEAD and your working tree to match the remote copy of master.